# How do you enable anti aliasing in arbitrary Java apps?

Tags: java, antialiasing

Many Java Apps don't use anti-aliased fonts by default, despite the capability of Swing to provide them.  How can you coerce an arbitrary java application to use AA fonts?  (both for applications I'm running, and applications I'm developing)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you have access to the source, you can do this in the main method:

```
  // enable anti-aliased text:
  System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings","on");
```

or, (and if you do not have access to the source, or if this is easier) you can simply pass the system properties above into the jvm by adding these options to the command line:

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
```

Comment: this method does not work for Substance look and feel, do you have idea about this ?

Comment: This doesn't work for `Graphics#paintString(String, int, int)`

Comment: If you're working with the Graphics apis, this may help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/renderinghints.html

Comment: Setting `awt.useSystemAAFontSettings` to `on` means *use anti-aliasing **without sub-pixel rendering*** which is most of the time (when using LCD display) **not** preferred. Instead use `lcd` value. See http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontRendering

Comment: The first setting alone works. That second setting does not need to be used. It's an undocumented, private setting, that has been removed from the JRE. See details: 
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6391267

Answer (score 9):

Swing controls in the latest versions of Java 6 / 7 should automatically abide by system-wide preferences. (If you're using the Windows L&F on a Windows OS then text should render using ClearType if you have that setting enabled system-wide.)  So perhaps one solution could simply be: enable the native Look and Feel?

In applications you're developing, if you render your own text directly, you also need to do something like this (at some point before calling `Graphics.drawText` or friends):

```
if (desktopHints == null) { 
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); 
    desktopHints = (Map) (tk.getDesktopProperty("awt.font.desktophints")); 
}
if (desktopHints != null) { 
    g2d.addRenderingHints(desktopHints); 
}
```

Reference: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/chet/archive/2007/01/font_hints_for.html

Answer (score 5):

For the record, I have found out that in my windows 7 machine,

- If I don't use this in my code, I get the nice ClearType subpixel rendering.
- But if I use this, I get the classical black-and-white antialiasing which is much uglier.

So this code should be used carefully. I guess it will stop being needed at all when all Linux users have updated to the versions of OpenJDK that handle aliasing well by default.

Comment: Try System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings", "lcd"); and you should get ClearType.

Comment: As a linux and windows user I do not like "cleartype". I purposely disable it.