# Java Applet: no antialiased font in browser (but in AppletViewer)

Tags: java, fonts, applet, antialiasing, appletviewer

In the AppletViewer, my Applet looks like this:
[image: screenshot AppletViewer]

In the browser, my Applet looks like this:
[image: screenshot browser]

As you can see, the font is not antialiased. Also the background color is different. And all the text is cutted on the right side.

What could that be?

You can also try it yourself [here](http://www.matha.rwth-aachen.de/~ilias/jars/Termumformungen%20in%20der%20Technik/Termumformungen%20in%20der%20Technik.html).

---

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179955/how-do-you-enable-anti-aliasing-in-arbitrary-java-apps/179971#179971) I tried to use this code:

```
System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings","on");
System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");
```

But that results only in this exception:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission awt.useSystemAAFontSettings write)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:742)
    at applets.Termumformungen$in$der$Technik_08_Ethanolloesungen.Applet.init(Applet.java:51)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1640)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission awt.useSystemAAFontSettings write)
```

Comment: Here I get only *Could not initialize applet.* error messages. (OpenJDK 1.6.0_20 (IcedTea6 1.9.7), Firefox, on OpenSUSE 64 bit.)

Comment: Opera the same. In the appletviewer it looks good (gray), but it does not actually shows what you have in the screenshot.

Comment: @Paŭlo: Uh, interesting... Do you get some error? What does the error console say? There must be some output somewhere saying why it can't initialize the applet... :)

Comment: The error messages (and stack traces) appear on `~/.icedteaplugin/java.stderr` (there is no Java console for the IcedTea-plugin, yet). There are quite some messages, but I'm not really sure how much are for each applet, since there are four or five on your page. If you made a page with only one applet, I could test more easily. The stack traces do not mention anything in your code, though. (It may have to do something with the spaces in your directory path.) And it is surely not related to your antialiasing question, I think.

Comment: As a way to hunt your antialiasing problem: Could you try to find out which Java version your browser is using? Compare this to the output of `appletviewer -J-version`.

Comment: @Paŭlo: It seems to be the same version. I also only have one version installed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work by overriding the `paint` method like this for each component where you want to have anti-aliasing:

```
static void activateAntiAliasing(Graphics g) {
    try {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        // for antialiasing geometric shapes
        g2d.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                              RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );

        // for antialiasing text
        g2d.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                              RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON );

        // to go for quality over speed
        g2d.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                              RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY );
    }
    catch(ClassCastException ignored) {}
}

@Override public void paint(final Graphics g) {
    activateAntiAliasing(g);
    super.paint(g);
}
```

Comment: is it really necessary to activate it each time you paint? or would one time suffice?