# 3 dots java title border

Tags: java, swing

does anyone know how to remove those 3 dots from java components?
my problem : a java widget with a title border which, after resize, keeps adding those 3 dots.

I would want for it to display the truncated title which fits that given area.
I managed to set its justification to the left but those 3 dots keep reappereaing...

or, at least, where, in java library, are those 3 points drawn? I searched through java libraries and couldn't fin it.

This happens using java 1.7

Comment: Are you sure this is just Java and not windows fault? The solution is to rename your title as you resize so the title fits the window size.

Comment: An ellipsis (i.e. `...`) usually indicates that the preferred width of the text is longer than that of its container.

Comment: I assume you mean the [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis), right?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know about the three dots at all, can you show us what you mean?

Comment: by renaming the title, you mean go to my componentResized() and recall setTitle?

Comment: Closely related: [How to check how many characters will fit in a title in a `JFrame`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65595184/16673)

Answer (score 1):

You'd normally do that in the UI classes. Here's a similar question: [Java JLabel/JButton: on some systems I get "..." (an ellipsis) and on some systems I don't. how can I force to disable the ellipsis at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380037/java-jlabel-jbutton-on-some-systems-i-get-an-ellipsis-and-on-some-syste)

Answer (score 0):

It is not Java or Swing who display the three dots (the "ellipsis"), it is the underlying OS (Windows, Linux ...).

The Java just sets the native window title property.