# Change font into IntelliJ 10 / 11

Tags: java, ide, fonts, intellij-idea

I try to change font for IntelliJ IDE with another monospaced font like Inconsolota.

I put Inconsolata.ttf (I use Windows) on the directory :

```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\jre\lib\fonts
```

Why doesn't IntelliJ make it available ? Is it the wrong path ?

(I precise that I well checked that IntelliJ uses this JDK and not another one)

Comment: On Windows you should just be able to install it as a normal Windows font, possibly restart IntelliJ, and it should pick it up as being available.

Comment: I prefer to use a proportional fonts such as Verdana 12.

Comment: Probably works on 12/13 as well, don't see why it wouldn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Additionally to copying fonts in `..\jre\lib\fonts` You need to change a [java anti-aliasing setting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html#aaFonts).

**1)** Add the option:

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
```

### Linux

```
<<jetbrains-product-dir>>/bin/idea.vmoptions
```

*There might be additional settings required for Linux and OpenJDK. Check the referenced links.*

### Windows

```
...\JetBrains\<<product-dir>>\bin\<<productname>>.exe.vmoptions
```

---

**2)** You then need to restart the IDE.

**3)** When you are selecting a font (`Settings>Appearance>Font`) you
        should uncheck "Show only monospaced fonts" in the little popup
        window that appears.

**4)** You'll be now able to see and choose **Inconsolata** or any other
        previously hidden font. Set the font size and line-height according your preference.

### Reference

- [How do you enable anti aliasing in arbitrary Java apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179955/how-do-you-enable-anti-aliasing-in-arbitrary-java-apps)
- http://gleamynode.net/articles/2280/
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-57233?query=inconsolata

Comment: Why isn't Incosolata treated as a monospace font?  I use it monospaced elsewhere (such as xterm)

Answer (score 3):

You can actually browse for your font.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Under the Editor node, click [Colors&Fonts](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/editor-colors-and-fonts.html).
3. Select the scheme you want.
4. Go to Scheme Settings, Font and click the browse button [image] to select a new font family.

If this is what you already did, and you couldn't find the font, even when you browsed for it, then you can install your font by running the setup.exe file that usually comes with it and try again.

Source: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/editor-colors-and-fonts.html#scheme

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot to point out that you need to save the default scheme as something else in order to modify it.

So under File -> Settings -> Editor node -> Colors & fonts,  select scheme, save with other name and then modify fonts... etc.