# Why do fonts look different in java paintComponent than in other programs?

Tags: java, text, fonts, paintcomponent

I am designing a simple text editor in java. I want the default font to be Consolas because it looks good in eclipse, but when I run the program the font looks really weird and nothing like what it looks in eclipse. Is there a solution and if so how do I fix? Thanks!

What it looks like in my program:

[image: Java Consolas]

What it looks like in eclipse:

[image]

Comment: You need to enable anti-aliasing. See [How do you enable anti aliasing in arbitrary Java apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/179955/5221149)

Comment: That's a completely different font, not a rendering or aliasing issue.