# What's the proper way for a `BasicLookAndFeel` subclass to activate anti-aliasing in Java 11?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I have this in-house Swing Look&Feel, and as is usual for a migration to Java 11, usages of `SwingUtilities2` members are to be replaced by official APIs.

Most are solved, but I haven't found any working advice how to crack anti-aliasing.

The L&F is built as a subclass of `BasicLookAndFeel`, which has mechanisms for anti-aliasing; however, these seem to require activation through `defaults.put(SwingUtilities2.AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY, AATextInfo.getAATextInfo(SwingUtilities2.isLocalDisplay()));`, which replicates what other Swing L&Fs are doing to enable AA, but with Java 11 this API isn't accessible anymore.
I have fiddled with setting `RenderingHints` in many likely and even some unlikely places, to no avail; for some reason, the settings never gain traction.

I am almost done analyzing the situation using the debugger (breakpoint on the L&F's `LabelUI.paint()` function and single-stepping through all the decisionmaking logic), but I found that `BasicLookAndFeel` seems to be hardcoded to use `AATextInfo` objects to pass hints, which I can't use if I maintain my own L&F.

So... what are my options?
I could probably use a different base class, but that's... scary.

(I know that @kleopatra has called anti-aliasing a "story-without-happy-ending", but this is about picking up the preconfigured hints and properly applying them, not about wilfully switching AA on or off.)

Comment: I always thought the usual way to enable anti aliasing is `-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on` and what about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11990630)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the linked question is about switching anti-aliasing on and off for existing L&Fs. This question is about implementing a L&F in a way that settings like this actually work.

Comment: Well, if your L&F does all the painting, then the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11990630) about the rendering hints should help. If your L&F does not painting itself, the global settings should help.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah. I accidentally edited out that the L&F is a subclass of 'BasicLookAndFeel' and tries to reuse of that implementation as much as it can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anti-aliasing settings from the Look&Feel are picked up by `JComponent.setUI()`.
In Java 8, it does `UIManager.getDefaults().get(SwingUtilities2.AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY)`.
In Java 9, it does `UIManager.getDefaults().get(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING)`.

There is no gradual transition so that you can clean up the API in one step and transition to a newer Java in a separate step, you have to do both at the same time.